# Understanding subfield test ( intuitive )

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, intuition

Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be a subset of $F$ with at
least two elements. Prove that $K$ is a subfield of $F$ if, for any
$a, b\in K$ with $b \neq 0$, $a-b$ and $ab^{-1}$ belong to $K$.

A field $F$ is a commutative ring with unity (1, that is, multiplicative identity) in which every nonzero element is unit (has a multiplicative inverse).

The way I understand this is that 
$$ (F,+) \ \ \text{  is an abelian group under addition} $$ 
$$ (F-\{ 0 \},*) \ \ \text{ is an abelian group under multiplication } $$

A nonempty $K \subseteq F $ is a subfield if it is a field with the same  operations  of $F$.

In group theory we have a test to easily verify that $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup of a group $(G,*)$, that is, if $a*b^{-1} \in H, \forall a,b \in H$

An intuitive way to see subfield test is to think that we have to prove that $(K,+)$ is an subgroup of $(F,+)$ and that $(K-\{0\},*)$ is a subgroup of $(F-\{0\},*)$  ... In other words:

$$ a+(-b) = a-b \in K  \ \ \text{...$(K,+)$ is a subgroup under addition}$$ and
   $$ a*b^{-1} \in K  \ \ \text{...$(K - \{0\},*)$ is a subgroup under multiplication}$$

if these conditions hold, we can say that $K$ is a subfield. 
Is this correct?...if it's not...can you help me? thanks!

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Though in multiplication it is enough to take $a\ne 0$ because you want to check that $K^*$ is a multiplicative group.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to be sure about this!